# PySpark - how to update Kudu table using jdbc connection?

Tags: python, jdbc, pyspark, sql-update, kudu

I have issues when trying to update  existing Kudu table via jdbc connection. Stated table is used both as a source and target and I am struggling to update several records.

My process is following:

1. I am using a jdbc connection to read the data from the input Kudu table named `db1.test_cls1`:
   Table has following attributes:

   ```
   consumer_id                   object
   merchant_id                   object
   log_date              datetime64[ns]
   beginning_period      datetime64[ns]
   end_period            datetime64[ns]
   first_trx_date        datetime64[ns]
   last_trx_date         datetime64[ns]
   tse                          float64
   rec                            int32
   freq                           int32
   ag                             int32
   mv                           float64
   p_mo                         float64
   p_al                         float64
   p_freq                       float64
   ```

Jdbc connection to read the data from the table: 
        `sourceDF = spark.read.jdbc(url=url, table=inputTable, properties=properties)`

!Note - attributes named `p_mo, p_al and p_freq` are initially empty and should be updated after the calculation within the Python code

2. Following this requirement, I am converting my Spark data frame to the Pandas data frame and calculating the attributes `p_mo, p_al and p_freq`.

`sourceDF.createTempView("sourceDFView")`

```
sql = """
    SELECT consumer_id
          , merchant_id
          , log_date
          , beginning_period
          , end_period
          , first_trx_date
          , last_trx_date
          , tse
          , rec
          , freq
          , ag
          , mv
        FROM sourceDFView """

inputDF = sqlContext.sql(sql)
inputDF.dtypes

inputDF = inputDF.toPandas().reset_index()


def get_p_mo():
    ...code for calculation...
    return p_mo

def get_p_al():
    ...code for calculation...
    return p_al

def get_p_freq():
    ...code for calculation...
    return p_freq

inputDF['p_mo'] = get_p_mo()
inputDF['p_al'] = get_p_al()
inputDF['p_freq'] = get_p_freq()
```

3. After finishing this part, I am converting again the Pandas df to the Spark df to be able to  perform an update of the table `db1.test_cls1` via jdbc connection
   This is done as follows:

`tarDF: DataFrame = inputDF[[
                            'consumer_id',
                            'merchant_id',
                            'log_date',
                            'beginning_period',
                            'end_period',
                            'first_trx_date',
                            'last_trx_date',
                            'tse',
                            'rec',
                            'freq',
                            'ag',
                            'mv',
                            'p_mo',
                            'p_al',
                            'p_freq']]`

```
inputDF_Prob = spark.createDataFrame(tarDF, schema=schema)

inputDF_Prob.createTempView("targetDF")

sqlTarget = """
        UPDATE 
            sourceDFView
        set 
            sourceDFView.p_al= targetDF.p_al
            , sourceDFView.p_freq = targetDF.p_freq
            , sourceDFView.p_mo = targetDF.p_mo
        from
            targetDF
        inner join 
            sourceDFView
        on 
            sourceDFView.consumer_id = targetDF.consumer_id
        and 
            sourceDFView.merchant_id = targetDF.merchant_id
        and 
            sourceDFView.log_date = targetDF.log_date
        and 
            sourceDFView.beginning_period = targetDF.beginning_period
        and 
            sourceDFView.end_period = targetDF.end_period
    """

targetDF = sqlContext.sql(sqlTarget)

targetDF.write \
    .mode("append") \
    .jdbc(url=url, table=inputTable,
          properties=properties)
```

And this results in the following error:

```
py4j.protocol.Py4JJavaError: An error occurred while calling o32.sql.
: org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.parser.ParseException: 
mismatched input 'UPDATE' expecting {'(', 'SELECT', 'FROM', 'ADD', 'DESC', 'WITH', 'VALUES', 'CREATE', 'TABLE', 'INSERT', 'DELETE', 'DESCRIBE', 'EXPLAIN', 'SHOW', 'USE', 'DROP', 'ALTER', 'MAP', 'SET', 'RESET', 'START', 'COMMIT', 'ROLLBACK', 'REDUCE', 'REFRESH', 'CLEAR', 'CACHE', 'UNCACHE', 'DFS', 'TRUNCATE', 'ANALYZE', 'LIST', 'REVOKE', 'GRANT', 'LOCK', 'UNLOCK', 'MSCK', 'EXPORT', 'IMPORT', 'LOAD'}(line 2, pos 8)
```

**!Note:** 
I also tried to do the update directly in the Hue editor and it worked perfectly.

Except for this, I tried to store the data in different target table by using the next part of the code, and it also worked fine:

```
sqlTarget = """
    SELECT  
          cast(consumer_id as string) consumer_id
        , cast(merchant_id as string) merchant_id
        , cast(log_date as timestamp) log_date
        , cast(beginning_period as timestamp) beginning_period
        , cast(end_period as timestamp) end_period
        , cast(p_mo as double) p_mo
        , cast(p_al as double) p_al
        , cast(p_freq as double) p_freq
    FROM targetDF  
    """
targetDF.write \
    .mode("append") \
    .jdbc(url=url, table=targetTable,
          properties=properties)
```

Could somebody assist on this issue - i.e. how to update Kudu table via jdbc connection?